# Printing out a Python List with unknown contents

Tags: python, json

```
def enumerate_all_config_objects(baseDN):
    url = 'https://www.AwebsiteThatIWontProvide.com'
    payload={"ObjectDN":baseDN,"Pattern":"*aws*","Pattern":"*jkb*"}
    r = requests.post(url, verify='/PathToKeyForVerification/', headers=headers,data=json.dumps(payload))
    response = r.json()
    status = r.status_code
    print " "
    print "Returned status code:", status
    print " "
    return response ['Objects'][0]['GUID']
```

---

Output:

Returned status code: 200

{11871545-8c5b-4c3c-9609-7372fae1add5}

Process finished with exit code 0

---

I am trying to return ONLY the "GUID" information from a json request. This works (the 1187154...), as I enter values into the index between ['objects'] and ['guid'], each value is successfully produced from the list. My problem is, even though I am printing out the actual response to verify the output is correct, the final script should not require anything being dumped to a CSV file. I have to perform everything in memory. The next function that I need to create will use the returned GUID values and query the server with those values.

How do I get the items in the list to display from the output of `enumerate_all_config_objects`? I would like to print them to troubleshoot initially. Then I will comment out this feature and have the second function pull each value from that list and use it.

Two problems:

1. Print out the list which will always have an unknown number of entries.
2. Create another function to reference / use the values from that list.

The list is populated correctly, I've verified this. I just don't know how to access it or print it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you are looking to do something like:

```
def enumerate_all_config_objects(baseDN):
    url = 'https://www.AwebsiteThatIWontProvide.com'
    payload = {"ObjectDN": baseDN, "Pattern": "*aws*", "Pattern": "*jkb*"}
    r = requests.post(url, verify='/PathToKeyForVerification/', headers=headers,data=json.dumps(payload))
    response = r.json()
    status = r.status_code
    return map(lambda x: x["GUID"] , response['Objects'])

def use_guids(guid_list):
    #do_stuff, for example, to show the guids:
    for guid in guid_list:
        print(guid)

use_guids(enumerate_all_config_objects(baseDN=<replaceWithYourParameter>))
```

**Edit : To clear out the questions from your comment, I decided to mock the call to the API which you said already works**

```
def enumerate_all_config_objects():
    foo = {"GUID" : 1}
    bar = {"GUID" : 2}
    baz = {"GUID" : 3}
    response = {"Objects": [foo, bar, baz] }
    mapped = list(map(lambda x: x["GUID"] , response['Objects']))
    return map(lambda x: x["GUID"] , response['Objects'])

def use_guids(guid_list):
    #do_stuff, for example, to show the guids:
    for guid in guid_list:
        print(guid)

use_guids(enumerate_all_config_objects())
```

prints out

```
1
2
3
```

When you want to use the value computed from a function, you need to use the `return` keyword. 
For example `return map(lambda x: x["GUID"] , response['Objects'])`, in this new example would return a map object containing `[1, 2, 3]`. This return value can then be used such as in my first example by passing it to another function.

In the example just above, the list is passed to the `use_guids` function, which prints the contents of the list.

**Edit 2** : If you really insist on calling a function that handles **one** GUID, you can do that in this way:

```
def enumerate_all_config_objects(baseDN):
    url = 'https://www.AwebsiteThatIWontProvide.com'
    payload = {"ObjectDN": baseDN, "Pattern": "*aws*", "Pattern": "*jkb*"}
    r = requests.post(url, verify='/PathToKeyForVerification/', headers=headers,data=json.dumps(payload))
    response = r.json()
    status = r.status_code
    for obj in response['Objects']:
        use_guid(obj["GUID"])


def use_guid(guid):
    print(guid)
    # Do some other stuff.
    # ...

enumerate_all_config_objects(baseDN=<replaceWithYourParameter>)
```

Comment: yes, but i am confused as to how i will get the list to print. it has to be returned to the function before i can work with it....? but it seems like i would have to have a loop somewhere to cycle through the index values and print out each position. this would ultimately feed those results stored in the list into the next function "use_guids".

Comment: when i print the output of enumerate_all_config_objects it simply produces one value. i need the whole list! I'm also researching the MAP idea. I never knew of that before. Thank you!

Comment: The `response ['Objects']` variable contains a list; in my answer, I am passing it through the map function which returns a new list that maps each element `x` of the original list to  `x["GUID"]`. That is the meaning of `map(lambda x: x["GUID"] , response['Objects'])`.  The new list is returned, and in my example is used to print each guid.

Comment: I'm restricted to python 2.7, and apparently this doesen't work correctly for me. I also need to iterate through the entire list, and this example just gives me 3 elements. One day it could contain 800 elements, the next 1200. I need to increment that value and have it gracefully terminate when it reaches the end.

Comment: I can live with it simply printing out all GUID items from the list and in memory, extracting those values line by line to place into another function.

Comment: @RyuHayabusa I am running python 2.7 too, this code should be working. Are you using the second example of code? If so, it's normal that it's printing only 3 elements since I declared only three elements  in the list... 
I have also edited the first example which should be working just fine. What error is it giving you?

Comment: I just added an alternative but equivalent way that handles the guids one at the time. Tell me if that works for you. :)

Comment: OK! now we are getting somewhere. The code prints out [GUID] 46 times. When i have a full JSON dump printed to the screen, there are exactly 46 instances of GUID data that I need to extract. It's in the format:              u’GUID': u'{7dh34w7b-b1c8-47cd-a986-b26aac194985}' so now, how am i going to get whats between the curly brackets to print out? we are so close! Thank you! I am using the code from edit 2.

Comment: If you just want to get what's in between the curly braces you can use `guid[1:-1]`, which will remove the first and last characters